# Skin feels sticky after washing off semen am I still impure?

Tags: ghusl

After I had sexual intercourse with my husband, I went to the bathroom to wash off the semen. I washed it with cold water and soap and dried myself with my towel. But after few minutes I feel some stickiness on the area I just washed so I went to wash again and it was gone. Does it make my towel impure because of the stickiness I feel after drying myself the first time?